# Database creation hanging

Tags: azure-sql-database

We have a powershell script that runs every night and copies our production database into a test environment. When it does this, it removes the test database and then does a copy of production. Last night the script died (not exactly sure what happened) and there is no test database listed in our Azure Portal.

When I try to manually run our script, it throws an error saying that a previous database create operation for our test database is still in progress.

Normally this takes about 5 minutes but it has now been 4 hours.

Anyway to stop this creation and start over?

I tried using powershell to remove the database but it tells me the database doesn't exist. I've also tried finding it in the Azure Portal but it isn't there.

Comment: This isn't a permanent solution but I went to the old portal (manage.windowsazure.com) and the database showed up in my list of databases in that portal and I was able to delete the database. Would be nice to see it in the new portal since SQL will not be available in the old portal come April.

Comment: you can use Azure API REST calls to check the status of this type of request (create DB):
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt643934.aspx